# Why does my xpage create a duplicate document each time it's edited and saved?

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage with a custom control that has a tabbed control on it.  When I edit the first tab and save it.  I duplicate document shows up in the view.  As far as I can tell the duplicate document is identical to the original, including the saved changes.   Why is this happening?  The onclick event of the Save button does an Open Page with a target action of Edit Document.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

MJ

Comment: can you show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button type is `Submit` that saves all datasources on the page. My advice would be to never use that type of button. You rarely want to save all datasources, even those a future developer may add. You usually want to save a specific datasource. So use the relevant method (e.g. `document1.save()`) to do so on a button of type `Button`. This will stand you in better stead going forward.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you so much. There are 10 tabs in that custom control and this is the only one with multiple data sources.  This was a simple fix and easy for me to understand.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have multiple datasources on your page.  Have you checked out this question?

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015953/xpages-conflict-is-created-everytime-a-document-is-saved)